# Function like thingies in array

Tags: c, anonymous-function

How would I be able to use functions in array in a particular way. Right now, I have it set up like this:

```
typedef void (*func_ptr)(void);
const func_ptr functions[] = {a, b};

inline void a(void)
{
    something = blah;
}

inline void b(void)
{
    anotherthing = blahblah;
}
```

I was thinking if there is a way to shorten this up a bit, maybe something like this:

```
const func_ptr functions[] = {(void)(something = blah;), (void)(anotherthing = blahblah;)};
```

Inline functions a and b contain only a single line of code, that sets some `#define`s.

Comment: I dont think you can do that in C.  Essentially what you want is to create anonymous functions in the initialization of that array of function pointers.  I think you can do this in C++ with boost::bind and or anonymous functions/lambda expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C you cannot have anonymous functions.

In C++11 though, non-capturing lambdas decay to plain function pointer, so that you can do:

```
typedef void (*func_ptr)(void);
const func_ptr functions[] = {
    []() { something = blah; },
    []() { anotherthing = blahblah; }
};
```